# Database design to javascript game

Tags: javascript, database

Hi i need help iam making a game in javascript. In javascript you have a lot of variables and i need store those variables to database. I want something like realtime database, but dont know if somthink like this exists. I want to refresh data in database almost every second in case that user disconnect without log out button his javascript variables progres will be save. Sorry for my bad english and thanks for help.

Here is example how it will work

```
After user login varibales for that user are add to javascript variables
Javascript game(player update difrend variables in game like stone,iron.)
Variables is send to database (i need store them every second)
```

Comment: There are thousands of frameworks, e.g. EmberJS that do that for you.

Comment: Is this a browser based game?   Do you want the data base local to the user, or is there a server somewhere the game talks to?

Comment: no its based on browser.  Progress player make its happend in browser using javascript and must be send to database.

Comment: thanks EmberJS looking good but i dont understand to witch database EmberJS sending data. Could it be phpMyAdmin?